# How to create Grouped bar chart

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, swiftcharts

I am trying to pass array as the groupsData. Here is an example of group chart by i-schuetz.

```
fileprivate var chart: Chart?

fileprivate func barsChart(horizontal: Bool) -> Chart {
    let labelSettings = ChartLabelSettings(font: ExamplesDefaults.labelFont)


    var groupsData: [(title: String, [(min: Double, max: Double)])] = [
        ("A", [
            (0, 40),
            (0, 50),
            (0, 35)
            ]),
        ("B", [
            (0, 20),
            (0, 30),
            (0, 25)
            ]),
        ("C", [
            (0, 30),
            (0, 50),
            (0, 5)
            ]),
        ("D", [
            (0, 55),
            (0, 30),
            (0, 25),(0, 25)
            ])
    ]

    var colors: [UIColor] = []

    for _ in 0..<groupsData.count {
        let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
        colors.append(color)
    }

    let groups: [ChartPointsBarGroup] = groupsData.enumerated().map {index, entry in
        let constant = ChartAxisValueDouble(index)
        let bars = entry.1.enumerated().map {index, tuple in
            ChartBarModel(constant: constant, axisValue1: ChartAxisValueDouble(5), axisValue2: ChartAxisValueDouble(tuple.max), bgColor: colors[index])
        }
        return ChartPointsBarGroup(constant: constant, bars: bars)
    }
```

I am trying to convert this arrays to the Chart instead of the gropsData. The group may  consist n number of bar.

```
    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"]
    let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0]
    let unitsBought = [10.0, 14.0, 60.0, 13.0, 2.0]
```

How can i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: @Ixx How to do this with arrays?